# How do I allow the user to add text the same way that snapchat does?

Tags: ios, objective-c, text

Where the user clicks on the screen and the keyboard and text field show up. Then when they are done it disappears and the text is saved. But I don't want the box to be around it I just want the words that the user typed to appear. I am somewhat a noob to Xcode, and I have been trying to figure this out for many days now. If you guys have any input that would be great!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please tell some of the things that you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to create a UiTextField or a UILabel.

In Snapchat the keyboard hides whenever you tap on the screen. Objective-C provides a methode to detect if the screen was touched.

Use `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

With `resignFirstResponder` you hide the keyboard from your label.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method, when method fired than

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
float position = [touch locationInView:view];
```

and add UITextField at that point, and on return of `UITextField` create UILabel with the calculation of text size and add it to view at same position where `UITextField` was added and remove `UITextField` from superview.

Or for touch you also can use `UITapGestureRecognizer`